# Spring + Ehcache - can @Cacheable be used to cache the output of a jsp view

Tags: spring, ehcache

Basically, is it possible to do this:

```
@Cacheable(cacheName="default")
@RequestMapping("getContent/{name}")
public String getContentByNameHandler(@PathVariable String name, Model model) {

    ContentService contentService = domainService.getContentService();

    model.addAttribute("model",contentService.getContentByName(name));

    return RESOURCE_FOLDER + "content";
}
```

When I try this, the view is cached, but the only the plain content of the jsp is returned from the cache, not the jsp view after the simple jsp view rendering logic has completed. I'm on spring 3.0.7, so still using the ehcache-spring-annotations (http://code.google.com/p/ehcache-spring-annotations)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`@Cacheable` works by simply forming a key based on all input parameters, and putting the return value under that key.

So it won't store the processed view - it will simply store the view name.

Normally, you'd use browser caching for that instead of server-side caching. And since rendering the view is supposed to be less consuming than generating the content, you'd put `@Cacheable` on the service method.

Comment: Ok, I haven't dug into the details, but in this case, cacheable is storing the plain output of the jsp, just not the processed output. However, this still answers my question, thank you