# Spring @Cacheable is breaking @RequestMapping

Tags: spring, caching, ehcache

I have upgraded my application to Spring 3.1 and all the jars have been adequately updated. But when I try to use @Cacheable for a method in one of my controllers, URL mapping for all the methods of that controller breaks. On checking the log files I found that the URL mapping for all the methods of that controller were never detected. I am pretty sure that my cache configurations are fine.
Can anyone give me some clue as what I might be doing wrong.

ehcache.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<ehcache>
<defaultCache
eternal="false"
maxElementsInMemory="2" 
overflowToDisk="false" 
diskPersistent="false" 
timeToLiveSeconds="300"
memoryStoreEvictionPolicy="LRU" />

<cache name="Backlog"  
eternal="false"
maxElementsInMemory="2" 
overflowToDisk="false" 
diskPersistent="false" 
timeToLiveSeconds="300"
memoryStoreEvictionPolicy="LRU" />
</ehcache>
```

configuration:

```
<bean id="cacheManager" class="org.springframework.cache.ehcache.EhCacheCacheManager">
    <property name="cacheManager">
        <ref bean="ehcache" />
    </property>
</bean>
<bean id="ehcache" class="org.springframework.cache.ehcache.EhCacheManagerFactoryBean" p:configLocation="/WEB-INF/spring-configuration/ehcache.xml" />
```

code snippet:

```
@RequestMapping("/*/backlog")
@Cacheable(value = "Backlog")
public ModelAndView getBackLog(){ 
    //sth here
}
```

Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Whilst @mana has explained how to fix this, this is why adding `@Cacheable` breaks your code. A recent [blog post](http://blog.springsource.org/2012/05/23/understanding-proxy-usage-in-spring/) explains this in more detail and is well worth a read.

By default Spring creates JDK dynamic proxies to achieve the caching behaviour, this requires that the class being proxied implements an interface which declares all the methods you wish to expose on your `@Cacheable` class. It is worth noting that you don't have to implement  any interfaces if you configure Spring to use CGLIB based proxies.

You haven't supplied any specific errors but often you get a method not found exception in this scenario. Spring tries to invoke the `getBackLog()` method on the proxy and there isn't one.

Comment: @pareshverma91   how Exactly you have solve this issue..kindly help

Comment: The link to the above mentioned blog post had moved to http://spring.io/blog/2012/05/23/transactions-caching-and-aop-understanding-proxy-usage-in-spring

Answer (score 3):

You shouldn't cache the controller method itself but the resource hungry method that will be called to create the backlog. Have a look [at this similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10404365/spring-ehcache-can-cacheable-be-used-to-cache-the-output-of-a-jsp-view). What `@Cachable` does is to create a key value map for your function parameters and the related return value. In your case this would be a `ModelAndView` object.

If you really need server side web page caching maybe use [this Apache Cache Module](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/caching.html).

Comment: Only this controller method calls a lot of different resource hungry other methods. So I would like to cache this method itself. @Alex answer solved my issue. Also I wanted to cache ModelAndView and not the final view due to other components that need to be added by interceptors. Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 0):

you should be injecting your service class into the controller and caching the methods on the service class