# Spring Boot simple cache results in 404 error

Tags: java, spring, caching, spring-cache

I am trying add Spring cache to my project. I read the [getting started](https://spring.io/guides/gs/caching/) and some examples on the net and look easy, but when I use cacheable annotation, my method results in **HTTP 404** error.

These were my steps:

Add cache dependency to my pom.xml

```
<dependency>
<groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
<artifactId>spring-boot-starter-cache</artifactId>
</dependency>
```

Add `@EnableCaching` annotation to my main class.

```
@SpringBootApplication
@EnableCaching
public class MyProjectApplication {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(MyProjectApplication.class, args);
    }

}
```

Add a CacheManager Bean to my project:

```
@Configuration
public class ConfigApplication {

    @Bean
    public CacheManager cacheManager() {
        String[] cacheNames = { "videoInfo" };
        return new ConcurrentMapCacheManager(cacheNames);
    }
}
```

Now in the method that I like caching, I added `@Cacheable("videoInfo")` annotation. (This method's bean is annotated with `@RestController`). I added other method with `@CacheEvict` to reset the cache.

```
@Override
@Cacheable("videoInfo")
@RequestMapping(value = "/get-video-download", method = RequestMethod.POST, produces = "application/json")
public DownloadInfo getDownloadUrls(@RequestParam String videoId) {
    DownloadInfo di = null;
    di = downloadService.getDownloadInfo(videoId);
    return di;
}

@CacheEvict(value = "videoInfo", allEntries = true)
@RequestMapping(value = "/get-video-download-reset-cache", method = RequestMethod.GET)
public void getDownloadUrlsResetCache() {
    LOG.debug("Se ha limpiado la caché de videos correctamente");
}
```

Then, when I make an HTTP request for any method in this bean, I get 404 error. I don't see logs from error and all work fine if I comment these two annotations in the above methods. Any idea of this?

Comment: This might be similar to https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11187853/spring-cacheable-is-breaking-requestmapping